# Silencing numba warning

Tags: python, numba, suppress-warnings

I have a numba decorated function which is called by another class method. It keeps giving me deprecation warnings. To silence it I've so far tried:

(1) adding `@jit(warn=False)`, but throws an error that the option is unavailable

(2) trying to catch the warning with warning.catch_warnings()

None seems to work, interestingly enough, if I break before the execution of the function and run in the debug console the same statement (`with warnings.catch_warnings()` etc.) and then run the method, it will silence it, but if I run the .py fully it doesn't silence it. Any ideas?

```
@jit
def annualize(data, freq=12, type='log'):

    T = data.shape[1]
    N = data.shape[0]
    rets = np.zeros([N,T-freq])
    for t in range(freq, T):
        valid = (data[:, t-freq] != 0.0) * (data[:, t] != 0.0)
        data0 = data[:, t-freq] * valid
        data1 = data[:, t] * valid
        if type == 'log':
            rets[:, t-freq] = np.log(data1) - np.log(data0)
        elif type == 'perc':
            rets[:, t-freq] = data1 / data0 - 1

    rets[np.where(np.isnan(rets))] = 0
    return rets

[... other code and classes ...]

 class MyClass:

   def __init__(self, args): 
       self.args = args
 
   def set_returns(self, freq = 'annual'):
       with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter('ignore', category=NumbaDeprecationWarning)
            warnings.simplefilter('ignore', category=NumbaPendingDeprecationWarning)
            if freq == 'annual':
                self.r = annualize(self.total_return.values, type='perc')
                self.log_r = annualize(self.total_return.values, type='log')
            elif freq == 'monthly':
                self.r = annualize(self.total_return.values, freq=1, type='perc')
                self.log_r = annualize(self.total_return.values, freq=1, type='log')
```

Comment: Is this the warning you are getting?

`NumbaDeprecationWarning: Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected, this is deprecated behaviour.`

Comment: This was indeed the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing `annualize()` this way

```
>>> values = np.random.random((5, 24))
>>> values[3, 7] = np.nan
>>> annualize(values)
```

produces a long list of messages that can be summarized as this error:

```
 >>> zeros(list(int64)<iv=None>)
 No implementation of function Function(<intrinsic stub>) found for signature:    
 >>> stub(list(int64)<iv=None>)
```

This means you are calling `zeros()` with a list instead of a tuple.

After correcting this, another error appears (summarized):

```
>>> setitem(array(float64, 2d, C), UniTuple(array(int64, 1d, C) x 2), Literal[int](0))
Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
   NotImplementedError: only one advanced index supported
rets[np.where(np.isnan(rets))] = 0
```

This means Numba can only use advanced indexing in one dimension.

Either error causes Numba to fall back to standard Python, equivalent to removing the `@jit` decorator. So your code works, but it doesn't use Numba at all.

And the warning says your code will fail with future Numba versions:

```
NumbaDeprecationWarning: 
Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode
compilation path has been detected, this is deprecated behaviour.
```

The second problem (advanced indexing in more than one dimension) can be solved by using one dimension only:

```
@nb.njit
def annualize2(data, freq=12, type='log'):

    N, T = data.shape
    ret_shape = (N, T - freq)
    rets = np.zeros(ret_shape)
    for t in range(freq, T):
        valid = (data[:, t - freq] != 0.0) * (data[:, t] != 0.0)
        data0 = data[:, t - freq] * valid
        data1 = data[:, t] * valid
        if type == 'log':
            rets[:, t - freq] = np.log(data1) - np.log(data0)
        elif type == 'perc':
            rets[:, t - freq] = data1 / data0 - 1

    rets = rets.ravel()
    rets[np.isnan(rets)] = 0
    return rets.reshape(ret_shape)
```

This version doesn't produce errors or warnings (Numba does compile it) and produces the same results as the original.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this works perfectly thanks. I was just wondering: let's say I just wanted to silence the warning (ok, fine, numba cannot execute, it falls back to python). Why aren't my attempts working?